# Cocos2d-x 3.7 C++ CCLoad UIPageView crashing

Tags: c++, ios, crash, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

This happens on all platforms but this description is for iPhone 5s 8.4 simulator, through the Xcode.

I have been working on the game using C++ and cocos2d-x version 3.6 and Cocostudio 2.3.1. All was fine until i updated to the official release of cocos 3.7. App started getting crashes. One of those is particularly interesting regarding UIPageView. So my header and cpp files are like that:

MKEpochSelectionScene.h

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "cocos-ext.h"
#include <cocos/ui/CocosGUI.h>

class MKEpochSelectionScene : public cocos2d::Scene {

public:
    bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(MKEpochSelectionScene);
private:
    cocos2d::ui::PageView * mainPageView;
    void previousEpoch(Ref* pSender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType eEventType);
    void nextEpoch(Ref* pSender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType eEventType);
    void showEpoch(Ref* pSender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType eEventType);
};
```

MKEpochSelectionScene.cpp

```
#include "MKEpochSelectionScene.h"
#include <editor-support/cocostudio/CocoStudio.h>
#include "MKGameScene.h"
#include "MKLevelSelectionScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

bool MKEpochSelectionScene::init()
{
    if(!Scene::init()) return false;

    auto node = CSLoader::createNode("UI/Epoch/Layer.csb");
    this->addChild(node);

    auto buttonLeft = node->getChildByName<ui::Button *>("Button_Left");
    CCASSERT(buttonLeft != nullptr, "Button left is null");
    buttonLeft->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(MKEpochSelectionScene::nextEpoch,this));

    auto buttonRight = node->getChildByName<ui::Button *>("Button_Right");
    CCASSERT(buttonRight != nullptr, "Button right is null");
    buttonRight->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(MKEpochSelectionScene::previousEpoch,this));

//******CRASHING LINE

    mainPageView = (cocos2d::ui::PageView *)node->getChildByName("selectEpoch");

//******CRASHING LINE

    CCASSERT(mainPageView != nullptr, "Main pageview is nil");
    CCASSERT(mainPageView->getPages().size() > 0, "Page view has zero pages");

return true;
}

//Other methods
//....

}
```

Sooo.... The thing happens with the mainPageView. Crash occurs on the line where i reference UIPageView from the design file and assign it to the mainPageView ivar. Crash does not say anything, but crashes in the NavMesh file at the following:

[image]

So it crashes when i try to pushscene as to switch to this scene from mainMenu. There is one more thing... If i use local variable like: auto mainPageView instead of ivar in the init() method, it does not crash. And if i comment the UIPageView referencing at all e.g. crashing line - it does not crash.

What i have tried: Updated Cocostudio to 2.3.1.1 which is the latest. Republished all of the UI using that new version. Cleaned all caches and stuff of the build. Updates to the new cocos engine version by creating new project with the new version and copying over files from the old version and importing into the project. This is just to say that i have tried several things.

Any help would be appreciated. And i am sure this might be a silly mistake of mine...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are triggering this bug:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/12962

It is going to fixed in v3.7.1